# How can I get my photos from TWITTER using Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, twitter, photos

```
$twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter('myusername', 'mypassword');
$response = $twitter-> ?????????;
```

Naybosy cna elp

Comment: Twitter does not store photos. They are managed by third party services like twitpic or yfrog.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter have disabled basic authentication and Zend Framework updated their library accordingly to use OAuth.

You'll need to consult the current documentation for [Zend_Service_Twitter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.twitter.html) and make changes to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Saying twitter doesn't do images is incorrect, they added their own image upload service as part of an update in June 2011 and also store references to all images uploaded by the user using third party applications.

You can see this by looking the urls: `https://twitter.com/#!/<twitter-username>/media/grid`

But Zend framework currently doesn't offer an easy way to grab these. I am looking to do this myself and thinking I will combine the Zend twitter search functionality along with looking at the parameters for entities and media within the twitter api docs:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.twitter.html#zend.service.twitter.search

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities

I will post back if I do this anytime soon with a link to the code.